# How to echo null in null values in mysql php query

Tags: php, html, mysql, null

When you perform a query in workbench, the null values are shown as *null*, but in php queries to echo the results in html, the null values just appears empty.
Is there any way to literally echo *null*?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($value === null) {
  echo 'null';
}
```

Or

```
echo $value === null ? 'null' : $value;
```

That is to echo null, test to see if it null first.

Comment: If OP is using PHP 7, using the [Null Coalesce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) operator is even more simple. `echo $value ?? 'null'`;